# HTML5 video element and jQuery in a Chrome extension's content script

Tags: jquery, html, video, google-chrome-extension

In the console, if I use: `$("#player > video").videoWidth` I get the result: `1920` (or whatever).

But in a Chrome extension's *content script*, `console.log($("#player-api video").videoWidth);` produces the result `undefined`. To get the number `1920` I must use `console.log($("#player-api video").get(0).videoWidth);`

Similarly, on the console I can do:

```
video = $("#player > video")
video.style.width = "1920px"
```

**And the css style's width *will* change** in the video element.

The code `$("#player-api video").css("width", '"' + video_width + 'px"');` does *not* work from the *content script*. This is strange, because `$("#player-api video").css("zoom", "reset")` does. So something is specifically strange with the element's style width and height. We can see this by looking further:

From the *content script* I must set `$("#player-api video").get(0).style.width = "1920px"` or use `video = $("#player-api video").get(0)` and set the `video.style.width`. This is because `$("#player-api video")` has no style property. However setting the `style.width` from any `foo.get(0)` will not change the element's style.

Finally, from the console if I try to use the method `$("#player > video").width` directly, I find it is a property (and it is not set to anything). Setting this property has no effect on the element's style, but it is at least there. But from the *content script* it is a method which has no effect on the element.

Why does the HTML5VideoElement behave like this? Typically elements never require using `.get(0)` to inspect or manipulate.

And *how can I change the element style (width and height) of an HTML5 video element from a Chrome extension's **content script**?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer to *half* of my question.

```
var video = $("#player-api video").get(0);

for (method in video) { 1; } // ensure all methods are loaded up

var css = video.style.cssText;
video.style.cssText = css.replace(/width:\ \d+\S+/, "width: " + video.videoHeight + 'px;').replace(/height:\ \d+\S+/, "height: " + video.videoWidth + 'px;');
```

*Will* change the actual style and observed width and height of the video element from the *content script*. This suffices for my needs, but doesn't really *explain* what is going on.

If someone comes and answers *why* the video element's `.style.width` can be assigned from the console successfully changing the element's style, but `.style.width` can **not** be so assigned from a *content script*, I'll award the answer to them. Otherwise, I'm claiming it in two days for the `.style.cssText` solution I found when inspecting the object.